# Check for days grace period in xslt

Tags: xslt-2.0

I am trying to compare 2 dates inside an XML file and using a XSLT to see, day difference is between -15 or +15(grace period) ?

For example I have 2 dates in XML:

2017-06-10 and 2017-05-27 : difference is grater than -15 and less than +15 = true

2017-06-10 and 2017-06-22 : difference is grater than -15 and less than +15 = true

**An XSLT 2.0 solution**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:value-of select="days-from-duration(
                                         xs:date('2017-06-10')
                                         - xs:date(xs:date('2017-05-27'))
                      )"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will give me the difference but how to check, whether difference is with in + and - 15 days. Can anyone shed any light?

Comment: Well, your current code using https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-days-from-duration gives you an `xs:integer` and if you want to compare its value to two other integers you can simply write it using e.g. `$days gt -15 and $days lt 15`.

Comment: Thank you Martin.